# Maven: run `test` stage and `integration-test` stage in parallel

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have a Kotlin project using a Maven build. The test class names adhere to the conventions, i.e.:

- `*Test.kt` for unit tests (JUnit)
- `*IT.kt` for integration tests (Spring Boot)

To speed up my Jenkins build I would like to run the unit tests and integration tests in parallel using Jenkins' parallel executor. There is no specific configuration in the `pom.xml`, so I expect the following to work:

- compile all classes and test classes
- run the unit tests by running the maven stage directly using the Surefire plugin (i.e. without preceding stages): `mvn surefire:test`
- run the integration tests the same way but using the Failsafe plugin: `mvn failsafe:integration-test`

From my Jenkinsfile:

```
// Jenkinsfile
...
        stage("Compile") {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh "./mvnw clean compile test-compile"
                }
            }
        }

        stage("Test") {
            parallel {
                stage("Unit Tests") {
                    steps {
                        script {
                           sh "./mvnw surefire:test"
                        }
                    }
                }

                stage("Integration Tests") {
                    steps {
                          sh "./mvnw failsafe:verify"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
...
```

However, that does not seem to work, because no tests are run (neither unit- nor integration-tests).

When running `mvn test` the unit tests are correctly run.

`mvn integration-test` does not run any of the integration tests with the suffix `..IT`. I assume that's because it uses the Surefire plugin (which has different naming conventions for integration tests) and not the Failsafe plugin.
It also runs the unit tests again, I assume because the `test` stage precedes the `integration-test` stage.

What is the recommended way to run unit-tests and integration-tests in parallel without having to compile twice?

Comment: Can you show your pom file? Why do you really needed to run integration test outside of the life cycle as well as the tests? How long takes it to run unit tests? How many unit tests do you have? Which Maven version do you use?